# How to map int to const char pointer C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a char array: char aBoard [64]
I would like to map some ints to pointers to indexes of the array, sort of
like:

```
 map<int,char*> mTest = {{11,aBoard[0]}};
```

So that if aBoard[0] changes to hold a different char, accessing the map key '11' will reflect the change and not hold the old value.

Comment: @Dai: yes, when I index mTest[11], it returns the entire char array.

Comment: @fightermagethief: `mTest[11]` certain does *not* return an array (in fact, arrays can't be returned because they are neither copyable nor movable). `mTest[11]` returns a reference to a `char*`. The `char*` will be the one put into the map (or `nullptr`). You may want to find out how to print `char*` as pointers rather than strings...

Comment: @fightermagethief: I bet it didn't return a whole array. I bet that whatever you used to look at the pointer assumed it was a character string and just displayed it all starting at the pointer.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Okay, yeah dereferencing seems to work here.      cout<<*mTest[11]<<endl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aBoard[0]` is an lvalue to `char` which is not convertible to `char*`. You would have to take the address of that, for example with `&aBoard[0]`.